# Iterate over all rows and columns in table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in a worksheet that I want to iterate over and change the value of using a function I had set up. The function just calls on multiple Replace functions to change the strings.

My question is how do I iterate over the values in the table only?

I was able to do it with columns using the following code:

```
For Each cell In Sheets("RawData").ListObjects("RawTable").ListColumns("REQUESTNAME").DataBodyRange.Cells
    cell.Value = decodeEnt(cell.Value)
Next
```

But how do I modify that code to make it iterate through the rows as well? I tried using a combination of ListRows and ListColumns, but didn't know where to go afterwads. Here is where I got to before I was unsure:

```
Dim listObj As ListObject
Set listObj = Sheets("RawData").ListObjects("RawTable")

For Each tableRow In listObj.ListRows
    For Each tableCol In listObj.ListColumns
        ' Would using intersect work here?
        ' listObj.Cell.Value = decodeEnt(cell.Value)
Next
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was searching for a variant solution. Came across one at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495678/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can't use a variant iteration like that, you have to use indexed iteration.  Something like this (untested):

```
Dim listObj As ListObject, r%, c%
Set listObj = Sheets("RawData").ListObjects("RawTable")

For c = 1 To listObj.ListColumns.Count
    For r = 1 To listObj.ListRows.Count
        listObj.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value = decodeEnt(listObj.DataBodyRange.Cells(r, c).Value)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: What does the hashtag # mean?
EDIT: Nvm, I see now that it's a shorthand way of dimensioning it as a double.

Comment: Your solution works. There were a few syntax errors which I fixed in your post, but everything else was fine. Thanks!

Comment: +1. I always forget about the `.DataBodyRange` (would've caught that if I had tested the code but I was just going from memory :))

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim Cell as Range

For Each Cell in listObj.DataBodyRange
...
```

Comment: That works too. Even shorter than the previous answer. Thanks