# Inserting values into SQL Server table via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose I have a table in Excel with two columns (Name, Rate) (say, this table's name `tExcel`). Table starts at cell (2,1), and Date is static (in cell (1,1))

I want to insert those values into SQL Server 2008 `tRate` table with following logic

```
insert tRate(ID, Rate, Date)
   select 
       s.ObjectID, e.Rate, Date   -- date comes from cell(1,1). DateType is smalldatetime
   from 
      tExcel e, tSecurity s
   where 
      e.Name = s.Number
```

I've created a connection

```
Sub disp_cust()
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=xxx;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx"
Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCN.Open sConnString
adoCN.Close
Set adoCN = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks for help.

**EDIT to @jaimetotal answer**

```
sql= "insert tRate(ID, Rate, Date) SELECT s.ObjectId ," & Replace(Row.Cells(2).Value, ",", ".") & ",'" & defaultDate & "' FROM tSecurity s where s.number = '" & row.Cells(1).Value & "'; "
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, but the issue is definetely not related to your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sample, I assume that tExcel.Number is the first column and tExcel.Rate is the second. The idea here is to do a for each row in the table (or range) and create an insert/select statement.

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim defaultDate As string
Dim sql as string, bulkSql as string

Set rng = Range("A1:XX") -- Range of the table. 
defaultDate = Format(Range("A2").Value, "yyyy/mm/dd") 
bulkSql = ""  

'generated sample: insert tRate(ID, Rate, Date) SELECT s.ObjectId, '0.15', '2015/08/24' FROM tSecurity s where s.Number = '007'

For Each row In rng.Rows

    sql= "insert tRate(ID, Rate, Date) SELECT s.ObjectId " & "','" & row.Cells(2).Value & "','" & defaultDate & "' FROM tSecurity s where s.number = '" & row.Cells(1).Value & "'; "

    bulkSql = bulkSql & sql  

Next row

adoCn.Execute bulkSql, , adCmdText
```

**Edit:**
If you really mean a table, than you can use this sample based from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495678/how-do-i-loop-an-excel-2010-table-by-using-his-name-column-reference).

```
Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lr As Excel.ListRow

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set lo = ws.ListObjects("tExcel")

'The other code from the previous sample. Use the following ForEach instead

For Each lr In lo.ListRows
   Dim Rate as String
   Dim Number as String

   Rate = Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Rate").Range).Value
   Number = Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Number").Range).Value

   'Generate the query from these values instead   

Next lr
```

Comment: Thanks, @jaimetotal. First answer seems to be compatible to my needs. I've done all that staff, but I receive error: Runtime error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error. Could you please help. it occurs at line where query is defined

Comment: I've tried query by adding smaple values, it works. Maybe there is some kind of syntax error?

Comment: Hi Sher, my bad. The issue was the Rows.Cell(0) as by default, VBA doesn't start array at position 0 but 1.

Comment: Thanks. One more issue. Now error occurs at line adoCn.Execute bulkSql, , adCmdText. Error: Run-time error '-2147217900(80040e14)': Incorrect syntax near '55'. Sorry for such questions, I wasn't using vba at all

Comment: To clarify. My date is at cell A1, and I use it in defaultDate, Range of table values: A2:B4

Comment: Can you show me the value of 'bulkSql' when that happens?

Comment: how can I do that? You mean String output?

Comment: I think one of the problems is decimal separator. Mine is ',', but I guess for sql we need '.'. I've tried this:Replace(Row.Cells(2).Value, ",", "."). Now it is Incorrect syntax

Comment: That is the correct function. Can you do MsgBox bulkSql before adoCn.Execute?

Comment: Thanks. I'm done, just changed some apostrophes in the query (put it into my post).